# Can't install tmap R Package

Tags: r, cran, install.packages, tmap

I am having trouble installing the `tmap` R package. I am trying to install it using `install.packages("tmap")` and mn receiving this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: providers
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tmap’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm new to R, but have tried many of the basic bug fix approaches (Reinstalling R Studio, quitting and restarting a session, installing from a local tar.gz instead of CRAN) but none seem to work. I *think* the package is being installed successfully but is not being loaded. Is that correct? How would I get `tmap` to load correctly?

I'm using R vers 3.6.1

Cheers

Comment: That indicates to me that it is *not* installing correctly. I haven't seen that before. Try downloading the source (or binary) package directly, *manually*, and install from a local file instead. I've heard of corporate firewalls/proxies corrupting tar-balls or zip-files before, perhaps this could be an indication of this.

Comment: Did you check that _all_ of the Imports and Suggests are up to date?

Comment: Yes so I have checked and all imports and suggests are up to date. I have also tried installing the source package manually from a local file and still receive the same error. I've been able to install all other packages successfully except tmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `providers` is re-exported from `leaflet`. Please make sure that `leaflet` is installed correctly, and check if `leaflet::providers` exists.

I would also strongly recommend to upgrade R to 4.x, if possible. I recall that there were some packages in the dependency/imports tree that didn't work well for R 3.x.